# System/Product supports out-of-box priority queueing mechanism

Tags: c#, redis, rabbitmq, priority-queue

Azure Eventhub and Azure service bus doesn't support out-of-box priority queuing mechanism.

Using Azure Service bus we can create separate queue as priority queue but I'm not interested in that approach as that lead to concurrency issues etc..,

Is there any tested & proven open source project supports priority queuing? Prefer project/product which support c# based SDK (or) helper libraries to send and receive messages, if any

Comment: .NET 6 and later has the [PriorityQueue<TElement,TPriority>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) collection. What other features are you looking for? Are you looking for a durable (persisted) queue?

Comment: I'm looking for ready to use or off-the-self message broker which can support 1) message persistence  2) partitioning 3)single consumer per partition 4)priority message etc